# Filtering ListAPIView in django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using ListAPIView, but I can't filter the results. My code is:

```
class UserPostReadView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    model = serializer_class.Meta.model
    queryset = model.objects.order_by('-post_time')
    lookup_field = 'poster_id'
    paginate_by = 100
```

In this case, `lookup_field` is ignored, but the documentation says that it's supported for this class too. If I try to implement a custom `get` over a generic view, I don't know how to reimplement `paginate_by`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've found the solution

```
class UserPostsReadView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    model = serializer_class.Meta.model
    paginate_by = 100
    def get_queryset(self):
        poster_id = self.kwargs['poster_id']
        queryset = self.model.objects.filter(poster_id=poster_id)
        return queryset.order_by('-post_time')
```

Source: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url

Answer (score 4):

I know is late for this, but I wrote a little app that extends for ListAPIView and do this easier, check it out:

https://github.com/angvp/drf-lafv

Comment: Try to include a specific example of how you would use the app, don't just link to it. It looks deprecated now though.

Comment: Oh back in 2015 I thought the link to the repo that had an example in the README was enough, sorry.