# `lookup_field` doesn't work on `ListAPIView`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, lookup-field

I am creating a reddit clone.

**models.py**

```
class Subreddit(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True, related_name='subreddits')

class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    subreddit = models.ForeignKey(Subreddit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # API Views
    # SUBREDDIT VIEWS
    path('r/', ListSubreddits.as_view(), name='reddits'),
    path('r/<int:r_id>/', DetailSubreddit.as_view(), name='reddits-detail'),
    path('r/<int:r_id>/posts/', ListPostsOfReddit.as_view(), name='reddit-posts'), 
]
```

**ListPostsOfReddit**

```
class ListPostsOfReddit(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    lookup_field = 'subreddit__id'
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'r_id'
```

I am having a problem with the url named 'reddit-posts'. This url tries to get all a particular subreddit whose `id` is specified in the url as `r_id`. The problem here is **I am getting all the posts and not the posts specific to that subreddit**. So if I have 2 posts in subreddit of id=1 and 3 posts of subreddit of id=2, if i goto `r/1/posts/`, in theory, I should get only 2 posts but practically I am getting all the 5 posts.
I have specified the `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` but that doesn't seem to work. Need help! Thanks!

Comment: you're not filtering the `queryset = Post.objects.all()`, you get all the objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url) say that you would need to write the filtering yourself for `ListAPIView`.
See also [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753173/filtering-listapiview-in-django-rest-framework).

In your case, that would look like this:

```
class ListPostsOfReddit(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(subreddit__id=self.kwargs['r_id'])
```

As far as I understand the [docs for the generic API views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes), the `lookup_field` and `lookup_url_kwarg` attributes are used only in the detail views, not the list views.